# Is there a relation between Sleep() and synchronization?

Tags: go

Consider the following program demonstrating channels:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func pinger(c chan string) {
    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        c <- "ping"
    }
}

func ponger(c chan string) {
    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        c <- "pong"
    }
}

func printer(c chan string) {
    for {
        msg := <-c
        fmt.Println(msg)
        //time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    }
}

func main() {
    var c = make(chan string)

    go pinger(c)
    go ponger(c)
    go printer(c)

    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}
```

If I uncomment the `time.Sleep` call, the output is "ping" and "pong" taking turns in a nice, predictable manner. However, adding the comment makes the order unpredictable. I'm a Go novice and wondering what enabled this synchronization. Why does adding a wait time make the rest of the channel feeder tow the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a relation between Sleep() and synchronization?
>
> NO

Synchronization happens between value sent to channel and retrieve from channel.

```
var c = make(chan string)
```

Channel `c` can hold one value of type string at a time. Until the value is retrieve from channel `<- c`; function `pinger`, `ponger` cannot send value to channel `c` (i.e. pinger and ponger is waiting to send value to channel till the time you read from printer function).

So in your example, you introduced the time delay via `Sleep` func to read the value from channel `c` on printer function.

That's why you get nice and slow read with the help of `Sleep` func :)

Comment: But the same pattern should be observed without Sleep, because of the order of reading and writing should be the same, only that the delay will be much smaller. Without delay, the output is like "ping ping pong ping ping ping". Why is that?

Comment: When multiple goroutine sends value to channel order is not guaranteed. It might vary depends on reading value from channel. For e.g: I executed your program, output is `ping ping ping ping ping ping ping pong pong pong pong pong pong pong`.  Typically using `Sleep` in routine does yields allowing the other routine to resume. `main()` goroutine also executed concurrently.

Comment: You mean, you executed my program with `Sleep` and got the pattern you mentioned? If not, this is my source of confusion. With `Sleep`, "ping" and "pong" alternate (at least on my machine), and without sleep, they seem to appear in random order.

Comment: That output is without `Sleep`. That's why output comes in random, basically order is not guaranteed in routine.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being a total idiot, but I still don't understand. If order is not guaranteed, why does using `Sleep` seem to produce an order?

Comment: We all are helping each other in the Go community. Don't worry. When using `Sleep` it will block the goroutine from executing (you know this already). When particular routine goes to sleep, other routine gets executed in pseudo random. Try this https://play.golang.org/p/OuoyxRaCXb at your end. Order will change with sleep. As I mentioned before Sleep 'does yield, allowing the other routine to resume'.